# less -R is not displaying colors

Tags: bash, terminal, colors

I am on OSSierra, using iterm2.

I have a small project that does some simple parsing of markdown in golang which then prints certain lines in color to the terminal https://github.com/deltaskelta/readme. I am using this library for color https://github.com/fatih/color

Everything looks great when I run my program by itself, but I want to be able to pipe it to `less -R` and get my colored output in a pager so it would be easier to view long files...

I lose all the color when I try to pipe to `less`, there must be some issue with the underlying color codes, but I don't know enough about it to chase the issue down...

Any ideas?

Comment: that was exaclty the issue, there was a workaround to force color always in the source library. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some programs can detect if they write to a pipe or regular file, or to terminal (tty); they produce colorful output only in this latter case.

Example: `ls` does something like that with `ls --color=auto`. You can force color by `ls --color=always`.

You should see what happens when you pipe your tool to `less` (without `-R` nor `-r`). Are there any codes at all? Compare to `ls --color=auto | less` and `ls --color=always | less`.

If there are no codes then maybe you can *force* the tool to generate them even when it's used in a pipe (equivalent of `--color=always` option of `ls`). Check the tool documentation if available.